# Book on arithmetic and elementary number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request

I want to buy a book on arithmetic and elementary number theory. What are good references? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for, but I really like E. Mendelson's [_Number Systems & the Foundations of Analysis_](http://www.amazon.com/Number-Systems-Foundations-Analysis-Mathematics/dp/0486457923).

Comment: Human No that's not what I'm lloooking for

Answer (score 1):

I am using Elementary Number Theory by David M. Burton for a course I am teaching. The book is very nice.

Comment: Does it have arithmetic in it? Do I need to work on two BOOOKS one in number theoridad and another in arithmeticidad?

Comment: No. I think most books that cover elementary number theory (e.g., congruences, theorems of Fermat, Euler, etc.) will assume that you know basic arithmetic.

Comment: So I should work first in arithmetic then ELEMENTARY number THEORY ? Which book is better for beginners in arithmetic???

Comment: If you tell us what you have learned so far, then it will be easier to suggest books to go to the next level.

Comment: I have learnt some algebra (equations, slope, quadratic equations...) and some geometry.

Comment: You will also require some background about the notions of sets, functions, mathematical induction, relations, mathematical logic, etc. Some of this is found in courses which are often called finite mathematics or basic discrete mathematics. After that you can take a look at this book. Perhaps you can borrow it from a library and work through a couple of chapters, and see how it goes. Solving many exercises will be important. Many exercises in first several chapters will not require anything more than calculations with integers.