# Prove $1^{2007}+2^{2007}+\cdots+n^{2007}$ is not divisible by $n+2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Prove that for any odd natural number $n$, the number $1^{2007}+2^{2007}+\cdots+n^{2007}$ is not divisible by $n+2$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We know, $$r^{2m+1}+(n+2-r)^{2m+1}\equiv0\pmod{n+2}$$ for any integer $m\ge0$

Let $r=1,2\cdots,n,n+1 $ and add to get $$T=2\sum_{1\le r\le  n+1}r^{2m+1}\equiv0\pmod{n+2}$$

$$\text{If the given expression } S=\sum_{1\le r\le  n}r^{2m+1}\equiv0\pmod{n+2},$$

$n+2$ will definitely divide $T-2S=2(n+1)^{2m+1}$

Observe that $(n+1,n+2)=1$

Comment: Or match up the other side and be left with $1^{2007} = 1$.

Comment: lab bhattacharjee and ronno I'm sorry by question because it shouldn't be asked here but do you have some indication of a good book of elementary number theory ?

Comment: @Ewin, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541327/book-on-arithmetic-and-elementary-number-theory, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548210/good-number-theory-books-to-start-with, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350833/what-is-a-good-book-to-learn-number-theory

Comment: @Ewin, my pleasure. But, not sure why " it shouldn't be asked here"?

Answer (score 8):

**Hint** $ $ If $\,f(x)\,$ is an integer coefficient polynomial that is *odd* $\,f(-n) = - f(n),\,$ then we can employ this **reflection symmetry** to group the sum into **pairs that cancel** (sum $\equiv 0)$, i.e.

$\!\begin{eqnarray} \rm mod\ n\!+\!2\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{n\equiv\color{#0a0}{ -2}}\ \Rightarrow &&\ f(1)+f(2)+f(3)+\cdots+f(\color{#c00}n-1)&+&\ f(\color{#c00}n)\\[3px] 
&\equiv&\ f(1)+\color{#0a0}{f(2)}+\color{blue}{f(3)}+\cdots+\ \ \color{blue}{f(-3)}& +& \color{#0a0}{f(-2)}\end{eqnarray}$

But by $\,f\,$ odd, $\ \color{#0a0}{f(-2) = -f(2)},\ \color{blue}{f(-3) = -f(3)},\ldots$ all cancel out, leaving only $\,f(1)\equiv 1$.

---

**Remark** $\ $ Here is a similar example from this [now deleted question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1229221/242)

> How to prove that the number $$1^{2015}+2^{2015}+3^{2015}+\cdots+2015^{2015}$$ is divisible by $2015$?

**Hint** $ $ If $\,f(x)\,$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients that is odd, i.e. $\,f(-x) = -f(x),\,$ e.g. $\,f(x) = x^{2015},\,$ then $\,f(n)+f(-n) = 0,\,$ so applying [Gauss / Wilson reflection](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/44964/242)

$$\begin{align}{\rm mod}\,\ 2k\!+\!1\!:\ \  \color{#c00}{2k\equiv -1}&,\ \color{#0a0}{2k\!-\!1\equiv -2},\ldots,\ \ \ \color{#a0f}{k\!+\!1\equiv -k}\\[4px]
\Longrightarrow\qquad\ \ \ f(1)&\ \ \,+\,\ \ f(2)\  + \cdots + f(k)\\
 +\ f(\color{#c00}{2k})&\!+\!f(\color{#0a0}{2k\!-\!1})+\cdots+f(\color{#a0f}{k\!+\!1})\\[4px]
\equiv\quad f(1)&\ \ \,+\,\ \ f(2)\  + \cdots + f(k)\\
f(\color{#c00}{-1})&\ +\ f(\color{#0a0}{-2})\ +\cdots+f(\color{#a0f}{-k})\\[4px]
\equiv\quad\ \color{#c00}0\quad & \ +\quad  \color{#0a0}0\quad\ \  + \cdots +\ \ \  \color{#a0f}0 
\end{align}\qquad\qquad\qquad$$

**Note** $ $ Inserting into the sum the term $\,f(0) = 0\,$ then the sum is over the complete system of residues $\, 0,1,2\ldots {2k},\,$ and the reflection method amounts to replacing this by the *symmetric* system $\, -k,\ldots,-1,0,1,\ldots, k,\,$ where the reflection about the midpoint $\,0\,$ is given simply by negation $\, n \mapsto -n \pmod{2k\!+\!1}.\,$ Such reflection (involution) symmetry is ubiquitous, e.g. at the heart of [Wilson's theorem in its various forms.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+wilson%27s+involution)

[Guass's grade school trick](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/44964/242) for summing an arithmetic progression is the special case $\,f(x) = x$.

Above we used standard congruence arithmetic rules, esp. the [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) $\, A\equiv a\,\Rightarrow\,f(A)\equiv f(a)\,$ for any polynomial $\,f(x)\,$ with integer coefficients. In your case we have that $\,f(x) = x^{2015},\,$ which is odd, so the Hint applies.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/188691/242) for a similar application of reflection symmetry to a product.

Answer (score 1):

By taking modulo $n + 2$, and partition the terms as groups of two
each,

$$\begin{align*}
1^{2007}+2^{2007}+3^{2007}+\cdots n^{2007} \\
 \equiv1+\big\lfloor 2^{2007}+(n)^{2007}\big\rfloor+\cdots +\cdots \big\lfloor \ \Big(\frac{n+1}{2}\Big)^{2007}+\Big(\frac{n+3}{2}\Big)^{2007}\big\rfloor\\ \equiv1+\big\lfloor 2^{2007}+(-2)^{2007}\big\rfloor+\cdots +\cdots \big\lfloor \ \Big(\frac{n+1}{2}\Big)^{2007}+\Big(-\frac{n+1}{2}\Big)^{2007}\big\rfloor\\ \equiv 1\pmod{n+2}
\end{align*}
$$
Thus, the conclusion is proven