# Show that a given term is divisible by a given number

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let $k$ be an odd natural number. Show that the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{500} i^k$ is divisible by $501$.

This means that:

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{500} i^k \equiv 0 \pmod{501}$

I have researched on the internet for quite some time but don't know how to continue from here. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hint: what is $i^k + (501 - i)^k \pmod {501}$?

Comment: Very similar, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/427744/925076

Comment: Use the reflection symmetry of odd functions as in [this $2105$ example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/617439/242) in the linked dupe.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I see where this is going. I just do not understand why **k** needs to be odd? I understood that in other examples **k** needed to be odd to avoid making negative **i** positive. However, in this task, **0 < i < 501**, hence **i** cannot be negative?

Comment: @MikeM The pairing up and cancelling of opposite sign terms depends crucially on the fact that $\,f(x) = x^k\,$ is *odd*, i.e. $f(-x) = - f(x),\,$ which is true iff $k$ is *odd*. $\ \ $